# Regarding Assignment Operator Overload

Tags: c++

I am trying to overload the assignment operator and trying to use the "copy and swap" idiom to avoid memory leaks. I have implemented my own default constructor and copy constructor. I just need to know when in my main I say `a=b` and assignment operator gets called, then what happens at the parameter part of (line 2). I only want to know about the actions that occurred at the **parameter part**.

```
template <class T>
Mystack<T> & Mystack<T>::operator=(Mystack<T> source) // Line 2, 
//Passing by value intentionally
```

**Option 1**: Default Constructor gets called and whatever code is mentioned in default constructor gets executed on `source`.

**Option 2**: Default Constructor gets called and copy by value occurs and b's value gets copied to `source`.

**Option 3**: Copy Constructor gets called and copy by value occurs and `source` gets the same value as it was in `b`.

If none of the above is true kindly let me know what's happening actually at the **parameter part**.

Comment: What do you mean by "copy by value"? That seems... recursive.

Comment: I need to know. When I am passing the parameter as mentioned above in the code snippet and calling `a=b`, Then b is getting linked to source somehow. So what's actually happening. Is the value that object `b` has is getting copied to `source` via `copy constructor` or `something else`.

Comment: As I said below, the argument is constructed on the stack, with whatever expression you use. That might involve calling the copy-constructor to construct it, or some other constructor you haven't told us about yet, or some function returning it by value.

Comment: Please see the whole code and let me know. Thanks [link](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/77305/stack-implementation-using-vectors-and-templates-with-no-overflow-version-1-3)

Comment: To re-iterate: What do you mean by copy by value? It seems nonsensical.

Comment: A naive implementation would be to pass by reference like` 'Mystack<T> & Mystack<T>::operator=(Mystack<T> &source)` . Notice I have used ampersand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing by-value allows the creation of a new object. The way this object is created depends on the type of the expression it is initialized with. If the argument is an lvalue then the copy-constructor is called, and likewise if it is an rvalue then the move-constructor is called.

Both of these functions are provided to you by the compiler given you don't provide them yourself and don't declare any special member functions that would inhibit their creation (among other conditions).

```
MyStack<int> a, b;
a = b;            // Calls MyStack(MyStack const&)
a = std::move(b); // Calls MyStack(MyStack&&)
```

The purpose of taking by-value is to have a completely new object. This can be done in two ways - by copying the old object to the new one or exchanging ownership with an object that is no longer needed.

On the `a = b` line, `b`'s contents are copied to the parameter `source`. `a = std::move(b)` exchanges ownership with `b` by removing its "guts" and giving them to `a`. `a` now owns whatever `b` used to have, and `b`'s internals are left in a state that resemble a moved-from object..

Note that initializing a parameter by value is [copy-initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization), and despite its name the move-constructor may still be used.

Comment: Ohkey so the right word is by passing by value. I am actually `copy initializing` source.

Comment: @tanz Indeed. Also, even though it is called *copy*-initialization, you're not necessarily creating a copy. It could also be a move if the initializer is an rvalue.

Answer (score 0):

```
template <class T>
Mystack<T> & Mystack<T>::operator=(Mystack<T> source)
```

That assignment-operator gets its argument **by value**, which means the caller passes a fresh `Mystack<T>`, however that gets constructed.

As you implemented your own copy-constructor and no move-constructor, that one will certainly be called if not constructing in-place.

Nothing will be called on `source` by the call, untill you return and the argument gets destroyed by a call to the destructor at the end of the full expression.

Some examples:

```
using A = MyStack<T>;
A make_a();
A a, b;
a = b; // Calls the copy-ctor to construct the argument to op=
a = A(); // Directly constructed as the argument
a = make_a(); // Return-value is directly used as the argument
```

Comment: What's happening at `a=b;` line. So b's value are getting copied to the argument that's present in the assignment operator, 'source' in my case.

Comment: you seem to be a bit too fixated on "value". Yes b is getting copied, but certainly not by value, as that would pre-suppose a copy of b, which means we are back at square one. I think you must work on keeping making a copy and assigning separated, as they are separate concepts.

Comment: I do get the feeling that I am not able to ask my doubt clearly. Nevermind!

Comment: Oh. I think I got your point Since at the parameter part New Object is getting created so I am kind of assigning the values not copying or something. Am I making sense or still I am off track

Comment: Still too fixated on "value". In the calling function, you are creating the arguments, by calling some constructor, invoking a conversion function or calling a function returning by an object of the right type by value. No assignment happens, unless inside the ctor, `operator(Mystack<T>) ` or called function, whichever might be the case. Keep initializing and assigning separate.

Comment: Sorry my concepts seems very bad. Anyways Since New object is getting created so at most it can only be initialized. Assignment or copying can never come into picture. It can only be done at a later stage,

Comment: If you copy, you create a new one. Thus copying by value does not make any sense: You would need to make a copy in order to make a copy, which means infinite recursion If you assign, you change an existing object.